# How to build a variable from another variable

Tags: ios, swift

I hope the title makes some sense but what I am trying to do is to set a field value to the item selected variable from my dataPicker. I have been able to make this work when there is only one field to set but my project will have multiple fields on each view that will call data from the dataPicker based on what field it is. I hope that is clear. Maybe as you look at the code it will.

I have set up a test project to limit things to this issue only. So my variable to tell the view what array to populate in the dataPicker is either season or sport. the field that will receive the data from the season/sport array is enterSeason and enterSport. When the picker has returned a value from season, I want to combine it with enter to create the var enterSeason to set that == itemSelected. This language is very new to me so I am trying the only way I have used before to combine text and variables in one value. It is obviously not working.  Help is appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var enterSeason: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var enterSport: UITextField!

    var dataPickerView = UIPickerView()
    var season = ["2013", "2014", "2015"] //multi-season
    //var season = ["2015"] //single-season
    var sport = ["Baeball", "Football", "Basketball", "Hokey"]
    var activeField = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        enterSeason.inputView = dataPickerView
        dataPickerView.delegate = self
        dataPickerView.dataSource = self

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return activeField.count
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return activeField[row] as! String
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        var itemSelected = activeField[row] as! String
        self.enter"\activeField".text = itemSelected
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT :** <s>How do you show and hide the picker? Your code anly shows variable declarations and the delegate methods... answers could vary accordingly..</s>

Since you show the picker as text field's input view, set UITextFieldDelegate for each of these text fields .. and in the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` check which field becomes active with simple if else

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    if textField === enterSeason {
        activeField = season
    }
    else if textField === enterSport {
        activeField = sport
    }
}
```

And in the picker selector, set value of the relevant text field as per current activeField object

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if activeField === season {
        enterSeason.text = season[row] as! String
    }
    else if activeField === sport {
        enterSeason.text = sport[row] as! String
    }
}
```

Setting the delegate for your text fields in storboard/xib :

[image]

**P.S.
- Rename `activeField` to `activeDataArray` or somethiong more appropriate**

*EDIT 2 : As you mentioned, second approach i have mentioned below is not suitable for you because there are too many of these fields i am still keeping it as part of the answer as it may help someone else*

But what you are trying to achieve is very simple and approach is too convoluted / weird. So heres another way you can implement the whole thing..

The easiest (but still probably not the best) way is to have two instances of the `UIPickerView` for each field. you can directly check `pickerView == seasonPickerView` OR `pickerView == sportPickerView`in an if else block and do the conditional programming and you wont need the  `activeField` variable..

Comment: @luka I do not have a picker actually in the view, it is created programmatically with the following code

`enterSeason.inputView = dataPickerView
 dataPickerView.delegate = self
 dataPickerView.dataSource = self`

Then when the field is tapped, the picker appears and is populated with the appropriate data. There will be 3 to 7 of these fields across several vies so the idea of multiple pickers for each field is not a solutions. Is there a way to capture which field is tapped to activate the picker and then I could set the activeField var based on the field tapped?

Comment: I have tried your solution and I think it will work but I am not implementing in correctly. I tried to set the UITextFieldDelegate as such `class DispenseScreen1ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {` but you said something about setting that for each field. How do I do that? The picker is not populating at all so I am thinking this might be the issue.

Comment: Also, in the picker selector, I get an error in my second `else if { ` statement when I say `if activeDataArray === sport {
                enterSport.text = sport[row] as! String`. I get an error for only this line that reads "Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to operands of type 'NSArray' and '[String]'. All of the other `else if {` statements, using the same syntax do not return errors though. Suggestions?

Comment: I tried to use the debugger but the code never gets to the breakpoint I have put in the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` function. That tells me the function is not being called when I tap on any of my fields.

Comment: You can set the text field delegates in the xib/storyboard where you have added the text fields.. just control+click+drag form the text field to the view controller object in interface builder OR right click and then drag form the `delegate`... just google how to et UITextFieldDelegate and you'll get a lot of help..

Comment: Sorry to be so obtuse but your answer did not finish in complete sentences. You said right click and then drag from the `delegate`... To where? I did a google search and the first two pages were post from 2009-2011 using any language other than Swift. Basically, I thought I knew what to do but now that I have looked at those sites, I am more confused than ever.  I do have IBOutlets and IBActions for each of the fields. Is that what I need to do?  Also, I am unclear on where in the view controller I am going to be working.  Ack! I feel some confused right now.

Comment: maybe the issue is in how I interpreted you syntax. I used the actual word "textField" in the function. Is that supposed to be the name of my field? If so, is "enterSeason" the name of my field and the name of my variable?

Comment: I have added a screenshot to help you understand setting UITextFieldDelegate .. you'll have to do this for every text field.

Comment: Thank you for the image. It was very helpful. I am still unclear about the syntax for the `func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    if textField === enterSeason {
        activeField = season
    }` is `(textField: UITextField)` supposed to be `(enterSeason: UITextField)` ? Then my if statement would be `if enterSeason === enterSeason` ? That seems odd to me but I'm trying to figure out why this is not working. Thank you for you help.

Comment: You need to study and understand how delegates work.. check [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-uitextfield-uitextfielddelegate--mobile-10943) or many others like it..

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I will check it out. Learning, learning, learning.